# FPDF image not displaying

Tags: php, image, pdf, fpdf

I tried to put an image in my pdf document, but when I use that method it only loading for a while, and do nothing (no errors, or such things) only a grey site...

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('logo.png');
$pdf->Output();
```

So what I do wrong? If I only use text in the pdf, it's no problem, but with the Image. The Image is in the root-directory.

Edit: Added `$pdf->AddPage();` as per the comment in Ewan Heming's answer.

Comment: Does logo.png exist in the directory the script is running in?

Comment: yes, because, if i use a other file like ('logo_a.png'); he show me an error that the file doesn't exists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sry guys i found out the problem , the resolution of the picture was too big

Answer (score 4):

Your example doesn't include a method call to add a page to the PDF before placing the image on it:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('logo.png');
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: sry, forgot that, but the real script contains AddPage();